# Draw MKShape on MKMapView

Tags: mkmapview, mapkit

I use GEOSwift library which has mapShape function. That function returns MKShape. That shape can be MKPolyline or MKPolygon. I want to draw that MKShape on mapview. How to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to draw MKShape on MKMapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361644/how-to-draw-mkshape-on-mkmapview)